# How do I keep my Android app running when it doesn't have focus?

Tags: java, android, service, android-asynctask

How do I keep my android app running in the background even when it no longer has focus? What happens now is that, after being interruputed (e.g. a message arrives) and then when it gets the focus back, it just sits there with whatever had processed up to the point of interruption. Probably my design isn't so good since I can see no apparent way of having it resume from the point where it was interrupted. (One reason for the design is that it is imperative that output from a long-running query give intermediate results immediately instead of all at once at the end.)

I'd also like to be able to switch to another app but keep my app processing. I guess that amounts to the same situation as above.

Googling turned up **`service`** as a way of keeping an app running, but one hit suggested not to do this if the user must interact with the app, which is the case with my app.

I use one `Asynctask` to **create my database** (once; no problem so far if interrupted--on next execution, I just continue loading from where interrupted) and another `AsyncTask` to **query** it (this can be a very long-running task), but this approach doesn't keep the app running in the background. Any interruption either leaves output screen incomplete and dead or returns focus to user input screen.

Would changing the **query** feature (currently an `AsyncTask`) to a **`service`** be a good idea? Is it even feasible? (User doesn't interact with app during query.)

I currently have the following private classes:

`private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper`

`private class LoadDatabase extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Void>`

`private class QueryDB extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Void>`

Your input will be appreciated.

*EDIT*

The first Answer below suggests that using `Service` will work.

I think that Googling has suggested that my task will be simpler if I extend `IntentService`.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

Yes, `IntentService` is exactly what I needed. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36971432/2737933). Changing from `AsyncTask` to `IntentService` is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For true background tasks the only standard way is service or your app can be killed.

Problems with AsyncTask:

- non-static inner class can lead to memory leaks;
- it tied to the lifecycle of a process (not the host Activity);
- priority in the [killing list is low](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle);

Use service and send broadcast messages, form notifications to the user.

Note: by default services run in the UI thread, so still have to use threading.

IntentService is ok for serial tasks. If you want multiple parallel jobs extend Service.

Comment: --Thanks. Serial tasks OK. Not sure how to use threading in this context; have successfully used threads in several desktop programs, so I assume that puts me in good shape to pursue `service` for this app. Any tutorials/examples welcome.

Comment: I would try [first](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html). Then full-fledged example from [google team](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) (download [ThreadSample.zip](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/ThreadSample.zip))