# IntentService does broadcast but onReceive doesn't receive broadcast

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast, android-intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

**(NOTE** that at the end of this Question I have an **EDIT** in which I have replaced one method with what the Answer said to do in order to fix the problem of `onReceive` never getting called **and** added `onDestroy` to fix a new problem that cropped up after fixing first problem.**)**

Here's how I attempted to capture the broadcast data, but `onReceive` never gets called since `Log.w` never displays anything:

``````
public class MatchesActivity extends Activity implements DatabaseConnector.DatabaseProcessListener
{
  public static String SOME_ACTION = "com.dslomer64.servyhelperton.SOME_ACTION";
  public static String STRING_EXTRA_NAME = "match";

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver
    (
        new BroadcastReceiver() 
        {
           @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
           {
              String s = txaMatches.getText().toString() + intent.getStringExtra(STRING_EXTRA_NAME) ;
              txaMatches.setText(s);
              Log.w("MatchesActivity","`````onReceive <" + s + ">");
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SOME_ACTION)
    );
    ...
    DatabaseConnector dbc = new DatabaseConnector(getApplicationContext(), assets);
    dbc.setDbProcesslistener(this); // set way to know matches has been defined
    dbc.findDBMatches();
  } // end onCreate
} // end MatchesActivity
``````

Database connector:

``````
public DatabaseConnector(Context _context, AssetManager _assets)
{
  mContext = _context;

//This method, called in `MatchesActivity` on button press, does start the service:

  public void findDBMatches()
  {
    Intent i= new Intent(mContext, QueryDB.class);
    mContext.startService(i);
  }

  // Here's the service:

  public static class QueryDB extends IntentService
  {
    public QueryDB()            { super(QueryDB.class.getSimpleName()); }
    public QueryDB(String name) { super(name); }

//Here's the procedure that does all the work (and it does execute):

    @Override protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
    { ...
      publishProgress(dicWord); // a String
    }

  //This does execute but it doesn't send `progress` back to `MatchesActivity`,
  //which initiated request for service (note: `publishProgress` is so named
  //because `QueryDB` used to be an `AsyncTask` and I just didn't change the name):

    protected void publishProgress(String progress) 
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(MatchesActivity.SOME_ACTION);
      intent.putExtra(MatchesActivity.STRING_EXTRA_NAME, progress);

      this.sendBroadcast(intent); // THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM, FIXED BELOW

      Log.w("DatabaseConnector", "`````publishProgress <" + progress + ">");
    }
}
``````

What connection(s) have I failed to make?

**EDIT**

This is the CORRECTED method found just above:

```
    protected void publishProgress(String progress) 
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(MatchesActivity.SOME_ACTION);
      intent.putExtra(MatchesActivity.STRING_EXTRA_NAME, progress);

      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is `onDestroy` in `MatchesActivity` (which starts the service), necessary to call when service has finished its work:

```
  @Override protected void onDestroy() 
  {
    super.onDestroy();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  }
```

Note that `onDestroy` refers to a new `MatchesIntent` variable, defined as:

```
  private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
  {
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
      String s = intent.getStringExtra(STRING_EXTRA_NAME) ;
      txaMatches.append(s + "\n");
    }
  };
```

And `onCreate` in `MatchesActivity` got simpler because of defining `mMessageReceiver`:

```
  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver
    (
       mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(SOME_ACTION)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What connection(s) have I failed to make?

In your first block of code, you are using `LocalBroadcastManager`. In your second block of code, you are not.

Replace:

```
this.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

with:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: @CommonsWare--Right on the money. I was so close and this is so obvious. Ah, well. Thank you. Again.

Comment: Wow. This is great. App does exactly what I want (so far). and it was SO EASY to change from `AsyncTask` to `IntentService`. It seems no interruption can stop it. Time will tell. I will add comment if anything untoward occurs.

Comment: One very important task I DID NOT attend to is to `unregisterReceiver`. Consequently, subsequent runs contained duplicate lines of output--all correct, just displayed as many times as I had "pushed the button" to do a new search. In order to do so, I had to create a variable `mReceiver` and unregister it in `onDestroy`.